# Why does Naturalistic philosophy of science potentially encounter a circularity problem that foundationalist theories would not encounter?

Tags: naturalism

Not exactly sure what the circularity problem is and how naturalism could encounter it?

Comment: I think you need to expand on this a bit... quite a bit.

Comment: Because naturalism has no presupposed justification principles that are independently validated. Quine dismisses it with "*such scruples against circularity have little point once we have stopped dreaming about deducing science from observations*".  See discussion in this answer and the comment thread http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28470/how-does-quine-answer-the-metaphysicians-claim-that-scientism-is-self-refuting/28473#28473

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Explaining Quine's dismissal of the circularity problem in naturalistic epistemology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/explaining-quines-dismissal-of-the-circularity-problem-in-naturalistic-epistemo), which problem was characterized as follows by Ronald Giere in his Philosophy of Science Naturalized:

> The general idea behind the circle argument is
>   that the use of scientific methods to investigate scientific methods must
>   be circular, beg the question, or lead to a regress. A more explicit version
>   of the argument might go something like this: One of the things any study
>   of science must investigate is the methods (criteria, canons, etc.) scientists
>   use in evaluating evidence. To pursue such an investigation scientifically
>   requires using data about scientific practice to reach conclusions
>   about scientific methods. Thus, any empirical investigation aimed at discovering
>   the criteria that scientists use for evaluating evidence would necessarily
>   presuppose at least some of the criteria it was supposedly setting
>   out to discover. So not all the methods of science could be discovered
>   by scientific investigation. At least some must be discoverable by other
>   means.”